# Htaccess remove .php from url for a perticular file

Tags: .htaccess

In my application I have a file called sampleaudios.php

My URL look like this

www.test.com/sampleaudios.php

But I want my url to be www.test.com/sampleaudios because my client forgot to add .php in that and the url has been mailed to customers.

Kindly help me to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a rewrite rule. Just add this line in your .htaccess:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.